# How to get the count of Belongsto in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the count of the elements of materials count.

SubCategory:

```
public function materials(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Material');
    }
```

Materials:

```
 public function subcategories(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\SubCategory','SubCategoria_id');
    }
```

I want to get the count of the elements that have the subcategory_id

'quantidade' =>  $subcategory->material->count()

I'm getting error in 1054 Unknown column 'material.subcategory_id'

Comment: Make sure your relationships are set up correctly; in a `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relationship, parameter 1 is the Model, while paramater 2 and 3 are foreign and local keys, which Laravel tries to guess if not supplied. Please read https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many and https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse for more info.

Comment: @TimLewis in this case can work inverse and normal, it's working with the answer of Alexey

Comment: No worries; Alexey's answer is correct, the comment is just there for reference about what the functions expect/their default behaviour.

Comment: @TimLewis It's possible to use relationship with conditions, for example in the material ?

Comment: Yup; you can append query clauses to the end of the relationship, like a `->where("condition", "=", 1)` for example.

Comment: @TimLewis but i'm using an array looping

Comment: Hmm... Not sure I follow. You may want to ask another question about that and provide the code. (Note this question has been successfully answered and accepted, so editing it here would not be recommended)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you're using a custom foreign key, you need to specify it. So, change the relation to:

```
public function materials()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Material', 'SubCategoria_id');
}
```

And then use the proper relationship name:

```
$subcategory->materials()->count()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the relationship to count. This will count the items using the DB. You should use the function like this:

```
'quantidade' => $subcategory->materials()->count()
```

And in the model, you have to inform the id in `hasMany` too:

```
public function materials(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Material' ,'SubCategoria_id');
}
```

You should also notice that it would be better if you name yours classes and variables according to Laravel patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Does your material table have a `subcategory_id` column? This error could indicate it doesn't exist, therefore it's failing when you try the relationship.

As long as the column exists, the relationship should be valid and you should be able to count the results.